# How to set fix width in percentages for container Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a root container as: `.container-fluid`, inside this I want create block with 80% width of display. How to do that?

Comment: Why not just put the container *inside* an 80% wide `div`? Is there a reason you want to do it the other way round?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid w-75">...</div>
```

"w-75"-class is defined by Bootstrap and u can put it after container-fluid.

If you want exactly 80 percent you have to write extra CSS-Class like

```
.costum-w-80 {
 width: 80%;
}
```

Then you can put it after container-fluid

Comment: And how set this by center? I put `.w-80` inside `.container-fluid`

Comment: When you use this class it will center horizontal.